# Need an efficient select query

Tags: select, abap, opensql

I would like to know an efficient to way to fetch the data in the following case.

There are two tables say Table1 and Table2 having two common field say **contry** and **pincode** and other table "Table3" having key fields of first two tables (DNO, MPNO).

Here is the little glitch, In table3 data, if it is having DNO it wont have MPNO

So when in the selection screen(Pic no2) if the use enter any thing, result should be as follows

```
**MFID  |  DNO        |  MPNO     | COUNTRY | PINCODE**
----------
00001   |   10011     |  novalue  | IN      | 4444
00002   |   Novalue   |  1200     | IN      | 5555
00003   |   300       |  novalue  | US      | 9999
```

( as you can observe if DNO present no MPNO , vice versa )

Please have a look at the pictures for a clear picture :-)

[Table Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm8wF.png):
[image: Table Relation]

[Selection screen with select options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bjp8.png):

[image: Selection screen with select options]

The code shouldn't be long.

Answer (score 1):

**PSEUDO CODE:**

**Select queries:**

1. Select * from table3 into it_table3.
2. Select * from table1 FOR ALL ENTRIES IN it_table3 INTO it_table1
                        WHERE dno = table3-dno.
3. Select * from table2 FOR ALL ENTRIES IN it_table3 INTO it_table2
                        WHERE mpno = table3-mpno.
4. Loop at internal table 3 and build final table.
       LOOP at it_table3 into wa_table3.

   ```
   IF wa_table3-dno IS NOT INITIAL.
   READ it_table1 where dno = wa_table3-dno.
   ELSE.
   READ it_table2 where mpno = wa_table3-mpno.
   ENDIF.

   ENDLOOP.
   ```

Hope this was the answer you were hoping to find!

Comment: Is there any to achieve this using INNER JOIN, If possible could you send it..and what about the selection using COUNTRY..?

Answer (score 0):

Building of efficient select will require information about obligatory fields in your selection screen, as well as about alleged production size of all 3 tables. However, without this information let's assume that *table1* and *table2* are reference tables and *table3* is a transaction table, as onr can assume from their structure. It would be sensible to build selection in a following way:

1. Selecting data from reference tables. As you said fields DNO/MPNO are mutually exclusive then there will be no hits of *country/pincode* pair in both reference tables, so JOIN is useless here. However we can merge 2 result sets in single itab without any constraints' violations.

   ```
   TYPES: BEGIN OF tt_result,
            dno     TYPE table1-dno,
            mpno    TYPE table2-mpno,
            country TYPE table1-country,
            pincode TYPE table1-pincode,
           ...other field from table3
          END OF tt_result.

   DATA: itab_result TYPE tt_result.

   SELECT dno
     FROM table1
     INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE itab_result
    WHERE pincode IN so_pincode
      AND country IN so_country.

   SELECT mpno
     FROM table2
     APPENDING CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE itab_result
    WHERE pincode IN so_pincode
      AND country IN so_country.
   ```
2. FOR ALL ENTRIES addition allows specifying the same table in FOR ALL ENTRIES clause and in INTO clause, so we can fill our result table with absent table3 data by DNO/MPNO key.

   ```
   SELECT *
     FROM table3
     INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE itab_result
      FOR ALL ENTRIES IN itab_result
       ON itab_result~dno = itab3~dno
      AND itab_result_mpno = itab3~mpno.
   ```